# Delete matching directories in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, find

How can I remove all `run-*.achilles` directories in all of my subdirectories under Linux?

I tried `find /path -name run-*.achilles -type f -delete` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues here:

1. You should quote `*` to prevent shell globbing.
2. `-type f` tells `find` you want files.
3. `find -delete` won't delete non-empty directories. [See this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164873/108618). Adjusted solution from one of the answers there:

   ```
   find /path -path '*/run-*.achilles/*' -delete
   find /path -type d -name 'run-*.achilles' -empty -delete
   ```

It's not perfect, the first line will match `.../run-a/b.achilles/...`. I think. This command should match better:

```
find /path -type d -name 'run-*.achilles' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

It uses `rm -rf`, so be careful with it.